# Script not working either place on html or save as .js file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My script doesnt work though the database insertion is working. The message "successfully inserted" is on the saveclient.php page not on the index.html.

my script (member_script.js)- i put this on folder named js.

```
$("#clientSubmit").click( function () {
    $.POST( $("#saveClient").attr("action"), $("#saveClient :input").serializeArray(), function(info) { $("#result").html(info); } );
    clearInput();
});
$("#saveClient").submit( function() {
    return false;
});
function clearInput() {
    $("#saveClient :input").each ( function () {
        $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

my html

```
<form id="saveClient" action="saveclient.php" method="POST" novalidate>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" value="November 1, 2015">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="time" id="time" value="9:20 pm">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="memberid" id="memberid" value="10002">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Complete Address" name="address" id="address" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your complete address.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Phone / Cellphone Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone / Cellphone Number" name="number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Worked / Source of Income</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Worked / Source of Income" name="work" id="work" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your type of worked.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <span id="result"></span>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="clientSubmit" >Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"</script>
<script src="script/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>
<script src="js/member_script.js"></script>
```

my database query (saveclient.php) - is working, it save data to database

```
<?php
    include_once('getconnect.php');
    $clientid = $_POST['memberid'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $work = $_POST['work'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $time = $_POST['time'];
    if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO member VALUES ('', '$clientid','$name','$address','$number','$work','$date','$time')")) 
        echo "Successfully Inserted!";
    else 
        echo "Insertion Failed";
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you telling your query is not inserting data?

Comment: no, inserting data is working but the message after inserting "Successfuly inserted" in on the refresh page which is saveclient.php, which is supposed to be the page will not refresh after clicking the button save. The message will be on the index.php.

Comment: Should be: `$("#clientSubmit").submit( function () {});`

Comment: You do realize this code is an SQL injection attack waiting to happen.  You *realy* and I mean *really* should look at PHP's prepared statements or this website *WILL* be hacked.

Comment: tnx Jeremy J Starcher for the info, i will figure out that later.

Comment: by the way, this html form is within a section with id = register. does this matter?

Answer (score 2):

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var form=$("#saveClient");
$("#clientSubmit").click(function(){
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:form.attr("action"),
        data:form.serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);  
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Use this code, this will work perfectly.

Comment: I place this code on member_script.js, replacing my code still not working, the message 'successfully inserted' is still on the refresh page.

Comment: i put this  either on the html or on separate page member_script.js still not working.

Comment: by the way, this html form is within a section with id = register. does this matter?